# Ignore unused variables for -Wunused-variable

Tags: c

In C, is there a way to ignore the `-Wunused-variable` for a specific variable or statement of variable declarations. To suppress this error:

> new6.c:28:9: error: unused variable 'a' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable] 
> int a, b=3; 
> .....^

Basically I'd like to do something like this (without changing the compile/run options):

```
@pragma: ignore-me
int a, b=2;
```

Comment: Declare `a` on a separate line, and comment it out.

Comment: One option is to "use" the variable with something like `(void)a;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **gcc** and **clang**, you can use `__attribute__((unused))`:

```
int __attribute__((unused)) a;
int b = 2;  // avoid mixing these declarations
```

Comment: This works for every compiler I’ve seen. But is it standard? I’m actually not sure. I know casting to void is supported everywhere.

Comment: @kill-9: indeed there are other ways to squelch the compiler warnings: a `(void)a;` statement, actually using `a` in an expression that will be optimized out: `a = 0; b = 2 + a;`... The best solution is to not define `a` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The simples method is to trick the compiler that it was used.

Some examples (macro is only intended to be used with static global variables):

```
static int a, b=3, c; 

#define UNUSED(var) void var ## __ ## var ## __ ## var ## __ (void) {(void)var;}

UNUSED(c)

int foo()
{
    (void)a;
    return b;
}

void bar(int c)
{
    int a,v;

    (void)c;
    (void)a;
    (void)v;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cvj1hW

Comment: Double-understcore is reserved for use by the implementation, so this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Yes but I’d say casting to void is more than tricking the compiler. It’s explicitly telling the compiler that even though it’s unused, that’s what we want. It’s not a trick it’s clear communication.

Comment: @M.M ***`Double-understcore is reserved`*** it is not. The symbols which begin with double underscore are. But here I have no such a symbols.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. In C++ it is reserved in any place but in C only reserved at the beginning, never realized that.